# Which is a better framework for project management : PMI or Prince ? or there is a better alternative?

Tags: prince2, pmi-framework

I had done PMP certification about 2010 but I was not satisfied. There are huge gaps between practices on ground and PMI. There are many outputs that PMI suggests which are rarely a written record .
There are quite a few inputs and tools that are like motherhood statements e.g. meetings is suggested as a tool!

Comment: You are looking for a methodology.  PMBoK is not a methodology.  The gaps you have identified are the gaps between a framework and method.

Comment: Welcome to the site, but I fear this question is intrinsically subjective/opinion related. [Help] explains why subjective questions are difficult for SE sites.

Answer (score 0):

**What's better is what fits the specifics of the particular project you are working with**.

There are a bunch of [project management methodologies and frameworks](https://toggl.com/track/project-management-methodologies/) to choose from. Projects vary in scope, requirements, target audience, domain in which they run, constraints differ, etc., meaning that "the better" methodology to use will also differ. How you manage building a small e-commerce website to sell clothes will differ from [how NASA will build their software](https://www.fastcompany.com/28121/they-write-right-stuff), for example.

You have to account for the following:

> In theory, theory and practice are the same. In practice, they are not - Benjamin Brewster

Project management techniques, methodologies and frameworks, give you the theory: a set of rules, practices, principles, guidelines and tools that have been shown to work in various contexts. But **they can't give you a set of steps to follow that guarantee success on any project**, because as I mentioned, all projects differ in some way or another.

So as a Project Manager, you need to invest in [knowledge, skills, tools, and techniques](https://www.pmi.org/about/learn-about-pmi/what-is-project-management) to apply on project activities to meet the specific project requirements and constraints. It's then with experience that you start to recognize when something is "better" to use, given the specifics of the situation you find yourself in.